# Is there difference between "catch [Exception]" and "catch" in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, try-catch, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have a script which is transferring some files via SFTP using WinSCP.

A summary of the script:

```
$transferfiles = @("filename 1" "filename 2")

foreach ($file in $transferfiles) {
    $file
    $transferResult = $session.PutFiles($file, "/upload/TEST/", $False,$transferOptions)
    try {
        $transferResult.Check()
    }
    catch [Exception]{
        Write-Host "$file was not transferred."
    }
}
```

I just want to know if I need to use `[Exception]`? Why doesn't `catch` by itself work?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using two `try` blocks? What is `$session`?

Comment: I need to catch the errors at different points. $session is part of the WINSCP initialisation - I can't copy all the info in as it contains private connection details.

Comment: `catch [Exception] { }` is effectively identical to `catch { }` and both should work.  Does `$TransferResult.Check()` throw a [non-terminating error](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/09/16/understanding-non-terminating-errors-in-powershell/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`catch [Exception]` is identical to `catch`.

So you do not need to use `catch [Exception]`.

---

*I have modified all official [WinSCP .NET assembly examples](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_examples) to use just `catch`.*